# When using the ngResource module, my model is not updating properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small problem with Angular.
I am using the [`$ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) module to resolve "comments" from my server:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);    
app.factory('comment', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/comments');
});
app.controller('commentsController', function($scope, comment) {
  $scope.comments = comment.query();
});
```

I use the `ngRepeat` directive to show all  comments:

```
<li ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    {{ comment.comment }}
</li>
```

So far, so good.

I want to make it so that, when a comment is submitted to the server, the `$scope.comments` property is updated, updating the view. I updated the `commentsController` `$scope` to have a method: `submitComment` which is invoked from an `ngSubmit` directive:

```
app.controller('commentsController', function($scope, comment) {

  $scope.comments = comment.query();

  $scope.submitComment = function() {
    var commentToSave = new comment();
    angular.copy($scope.comment, commentToSave);
    commentToSave.$save(function() { 
      $scope.comments.push(commentToSave);
    });
  };
});
```

When this method is invoked, the "comment" is successfully sent to the server however, the view is not updated properly. Recall that my `ngRepeat` directive is defined on a `li`. When I submit a "comment", a new `li` is created (i.e. a new bullet point is rendered), but the body is empty. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I noticed that, if I call `$scope.comments.push(commentToSave);` *outside* the `$save` callback, the view is updated correctly. I think `commentToSave` is being changed when I call `$save`, something like that anyway.

Comment: What does your backend respond with? I think the $save function updates the values of the item from the response, so if it's empty, the properties of commentToSave will be empty as well. (You can see the response in the network tab in your browsers development tools, or in javascript if you have a parameter in the success function, `commentToSave.$save(function(result) { });`)

Comment: did you define `$scope.comment` ?

Comment: @Patrick You hit the nail on the head, friend. I wonder, is there a way to disable this behaviour..? I can appreciate how this behaviour can be useful in many cases, but here it is unnecessary. Also, please leave an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $save function updates the values of the saved item from the response. So if the response is empty, the properties of `commentToSave` will be empty as well.

If it's an option for you, you should return the created value from the backend. This is useful because often times you don't have a unique identifier when creating an item in the web page. The ID can then be created when inserting it into a database for instance. So when you post a new item, you respond with the "created properties" so your controller holds the correct ID of the item. You especially need this if you change any values and update the item a second time using `$save`.

If you don't want to use the response from the server when doing save, just copy the values to a new variable and use that when pushing the item to the array of comments. I'm not sure how you would switch this off in the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) factory, and haven't seen any option for it either.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I ave problems with answers coming back from REST apis. So in your case I would do something like this:

```
commentToSave.$save(function(savedComment) { 
    $scope.comments.push(angular.fromJson(savedComment));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the comment to be not changed:

```
app.controller('commentsController', function($scope, comment) {

  $scope.comments = comment.query();

  $scope.submitComment = function() {
    var commentToSave = new comment(), commentToDisplay = {};
    angular.copy(commentToDisplay, commentToSave);
    angular.copy($scope.comment, commentToSave);
    commentToSave.$save(function() { 
      $scope.comments.push(commentToDisplay);
    });
  };
});
```